# Maxlength em TextField

Tags: java, javafx

Tenho um Textfield em javaFX, porém não encontro a propriedade Maxlength. Em C# e QT5, já fiz alguns aplicativos, e é muito simples achar esta propriedade.

Tenho encontrado algumas respostas, no entando estou em dúvida se realmente preciso fazer isso "na mão" como as respostas dizem.

Existe esta propriedade no Textfield em JavaFX ou não ?

Exemplo de resposta para maxlength no JavaFX:

```
public static void addTextLimiter(final TextField tf, final int maxLength) {
tf.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, final String oldValue, final String newValue) {
        if (tf.getText().length() > maxLength) {
            String s = tf.getText().substring(0, maxLength);
            tf.setText(s);
        }
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: É isso mesmo, não tem uma propriedade para esse propósito e você precisará implementar seu limitador. Isso que fez está certo, mas também pode criar uma classe que herde de `TextField` e sobrescreva os métodos `replaceText` e `replaceSelection`, fazendo a mesma validação que faz nesse *listener* do seu código.

Comment: @Renan porque você não coloca a sua resposta como uma resposta de fato? A sua resposta está correta.